# Iterate json object to pass key and value to a function

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following json object and trying to pass them as parameter - key&value pair as an input.

```
var tablesEntities = {"HARDWARE": "HARDWARE_ID,HARDWARE_LABEL","SOFTWARE": "SOFTWARE_ID,SOFTWARE_LABEL"}
```

How could I able to iterate to pass key and value from the above json object to pass into the following method.

```
const test = await TablesFromX(key, value)
```

Actually key will be used table name, and value will be used for entities in the tables. I am trying to avoid manual work as follows:

```
const test1 = await TablesFromX("HARDWARE", "HARDWARE_ID,HARDWARE_LABEL")
const test2 = await TablesFromX("SOFTWARE", "SOFTWARE_ID,SOFTWARE_LABEL")
```

Comment: `await Promise.all(Object.keys(tablesEntities).map(key => TablesFromX(key, tablesEntities[key])))`

Comment: What you have [is not JSON](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)